# Ошибка ввода массива

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>;

int main()
{
    int a[30], i;

    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
        scanf(" %d", a[i]);
    }

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: У Вас формат аргументов, передаваемых scanf, неверный. Я думаю, стоит достать удобную среду разработки, например, Visual Studio Express, если Вы программируете под Windows, тогда многие подобные ошибки будет легче отлавливать.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>;

int main()
{
    int a[30], i;

    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
        scanf(" %d", &a[i]);
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а почему не верный? Как нужно?

Comment: @Alexandr Потому что scanf требует адрес переменной, а Вы передавали значение. Сравните Ваш код и код от shk. Разница в наличии/отсутствии & перед a[i].

Answer (score 0):

Извините!) Мож я че то не понимаю, но зачем вы a[i]=i, если вы потом все равно вводите значения элементов массива scanf(" %d", &a[i])?)

Comment: Это я по всякому пробовал, т.к. не мог найти причину!

Comment: @Alexandr Для комментариев есть комментарии. :)

Comment: Насчет a[i] = i;
не так уж глупо, если ввести не число (а например йцукен или ^D),
то после scanf() в a[i] будет i в a[i+1] i+1 и т.д. 
 (а м.б. это осмысленно?).
Еще вариант scanf (" %d",a+i); аргумент scanf() тоже АДРЕС 
32-разрядного целого.